# Troubles with Big O Estimate

Tags: big-o

I'm asked to give a big-O estimates for some pieces of code but I'm having a little bit of trouble

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 2) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j + +)
      sum = sum + i + j;
```

I'm thinking that the worst case would be O(n/2) because the outer for loop is from i to array length n. However, I'm not sure if the inner loop affects the Big O.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = n; i > n/2; i − −) {
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j + +)
      sum = sum + i + j;
```

For this one, I'm thinking it would be O(n^2/2) because the inner loop is from j to n and the outer loop is from n to n/2 which gives me n*(n/2)

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = n; i > n − 2; i − −) {
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j+ = 5)
      sum = sum + i + j;
```

I'm pretty lost on this one. My guess is O(n^2-2/5)

Comment: For the last one, outer loop runs only two times. Why would it be O(n^2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your running times for the first two examples are correct.

For the first example, the inner loop of course always executes 10 times. So we can say the total running time is O(10n/2).

For the last example, the outer loop only executes twice, and the inner loop `n/5` times, so the total running time is O(2n/5).

Note that, because of the way big-O complexity is defined, constant factors and asymptotically smaller terms are negligible, so your complexities can / should be simplified to:

- O(n)
- O(n<sup>2</sup>)
- O(n)

If you were to take into account constant factors (using something other than big-O notation of course - perhaps [~-notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)), you may have to be explicit about what constitutes a unit of work - perhaps `sum = sum + i + j` constitutes 2 units of work instead of just 1, since there are 2 addition operations.

Answer (score 2):

You're NOT running nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 2);
                                 ^----
```

That semicolon is TERMINATING the loop definition, so the `i` loop is just counting from 0 -> n, in steps of 2, without doing anything. The `j` loop is completely independent of the `i` loop - both are simply dependent on `n` for their execution time.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, but in that case wouldn't it still be n/2 because i is increasing by 2 each time?

Comment: It was clearly a typo, so I'm not sure why you posted this as an answer.

Comment: @Mohammad: it's also clearly homework, and homework can/does/will contain trick questions. it's not our place to judge if it's a typo or not.

Comment: The semicolons have been edited out of the question, so this answer has been invalidated. Also, technically there is no mention of a programming language (perhaps it's just pseudo-code), so technicalities regarding syntax is probably grounds for clarification before assumption.

Comment: @MarcB Hmm, possibly.  You should still have mentioned it in the answer that it may be a typo, but if not here is so-and-so answer.

Answer (score 2):

> For the above algorithms worst case/best case are the same.
>   In case of Big O notation, lower order terms and coefficient of highest order term can be ignored as Big O is used for describing **asymptotic** upper bound.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 2) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j + +)
      sum = sum + i + j;
```

Total number of outer loop iteration =n/2.for each iteration of outer loop, number of inner loop iterations=10.so total number of inner loop iterations=10*n/2=5n. so clearly it is O(n).
Now think about rest two programs and determine time complexities on your own.

Comment: Actually `..., number of inner loop iteration = 10` (not `n`).